# Automapper - Map Entity from 2 sources

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am writing an asp net core controller method where I am receiving part of the request in path (*agentID*) and the other in body (*scenarioReq*). I have to map this two inputs into a single entity with Automapper.

The way I have accomplished that is kind of ugly (I am not assigning the AgentId property after the *Map* call in order to be a single instruction):

`_mapper.Map<ChangeScenarioRequest, Scenario>(scenarioReq, opt => opt.AfterMap((_, dest) => dest.AgentId = agentID));`

Does someone know if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ResolutionContext` and pass the `agentId` as an extra dictionary item:

```
//In your mapping profile for <ChangeScenarioRequest, Scenario>
...your current member mappings
.ForMember(dest => dest.AgentId, opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, ctx) => (string)ctx.Items["AgentId"]));

//Wherever you are doing the mapping
_mapper.Map<ChangeScenarioRequest, Scenario>(scenarioReq, opts => opts.Items["AgentId"] = agentId);
```

Comment: Thank your for the help friend. This method *ResolveUsing* seems to not be available in the most recent version of AutoMapper.

Comment: @Gofu You are welcome, mark the answer as accepted if you find it helpful and it works for you.

Comment: it doesn't since the method doesnt exist anymore in the last versions of AutoMapper

Comment: @Gofu ok I updated it to use `MapFrom`, I think that one exists. I am on mobile so can't check but this is for sure possible with latest version of automapper. Also check that now it no longer assigns value in the lambda.

Comment: Yes I have tried and it works, thanks for you answer It was helpful althought I dont feel this is better than the *AfterMap* thing.

Comment: @Gofu yeah I agree, both ways achieve the same result - passing extra contextual information into the mapping.

Comment: @Gofu I just thought it might also work to `CreateMap<Tuple<ChangeScenarioRequest, string>, Dest>();` and then use `_mapper.Map<Tuple<ChangeScenarioRequest, string>, Scenario>(new Tuple<ChangeScenarioRequest, string>(scenarioReq, agentId)`

Comment: Hmm I really appreciate your effort, seems to be another solution for this problem, but it doesnt seems to be better than the *AfterMap* either. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Gofu The only argument as to why they might be considered better is because you encapsulate the domain logic of mapping agent id in the profile itself and that way the map cannot be consumed without accidently not mapping the agent id. That’s kinda what automapper is for, using after map delegate is basically redundant overhead now because you might as well just assign the value after the map call.

Comment: Of course it's better than AfterMap. Because it's saying exactly what is doing, resolving that specific property. So it integrates seamlessly with what AM is doing, for example validation. AM will know that property is mapped. AfterMap is a solution of last resort and definitely not warranted here.